# Video Upload using NSURLSessionUploadTask. Error "The network connection was lost.”

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file-upload, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I’m trying to upload a **video file** through service using `NSURLSessionUploadTask`. But getting an issue saying
`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost.”`  But I can able to upload **image file** without an issue. what would be the problem?

Tried both in phone and simulator and also did reset simulator settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop the project! and Quit simulator and restart it! Then also it creates issue then check your internet connection that it is working proper or not. Because some time bad internet connectivity also creates that problem!

Once check your server's `timeout` also and data limit also!

Comment: This guy must've love swift so much he even type like a swift syntax!

Comment: @Lion I have tried. Still the same issue is appearing.